# Problem with events in default.aspx page (ASP.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having problems with an asp.net webform that uses a master page. The problem only occurs when the page is named default.aspx. When named default.aspx if there is any code in the Page_Load event, other events do not fire. This also includes all code commented out I've tested OnInit and Button click events, the problem first manifested itself with button clicks not firing.

Default.aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TWS/tws.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SITMComAU.TWS.original" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyPlaceholder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**OnInit Fires: - Checked Via Break Point**

```
 public partial class original : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = a;
    }
}
```

**OnInit Does Not Fire: - Checked Via Break Point**

```
 public partial class original : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /*
            int y = 5;
            int z = y - 1;
         */         
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = a;
    }
}
```

**OnInit Does Not Fire: - Checked Via Break Point**

```
 public partial class original : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            int y = 5;
            int z = y - 1;

    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = a;
    }
}
```

All of the above work if the aspx, cs and designer files are renamed to anything other than default.

As for the master page. It is layout only, there is no functionality in the .cs file.

**What I have tried:**

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Rebooting
- Removing dll, pdb files from bin
- Voodoo
- Pulling out my hair
- Pulling out others hair

I hope some one can help!

Comment: What other pages do you have? Are any of them named `Default`? ASP.NET projects have the nuisance of not properly implementing namespaces automatically (if at all) so it might well be that you have type conflicts (i.e. enough so that the events are strapped to the _other_ `Default`, perhaps.)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment the project is a website, a few directories deep. Some of these have default.aspx pages. I was thinking along the samw lines which is why the class is "original" not "default" or "_default"

Comment: Weird, Voodoo usually works :)

Comment: Try make sure there is no problem with your masterpage. Maybe create a new one with the same contentplaceholders but with nothing else in them, then wiring it up. Also check trace.axd http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx see if you can see it going somewhere.

Comment: Also can you see the debugger going into your global.asax?

Comment: Still no luck, huh? Maybe you can send me the source file and I'll try and duplicate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

May be the event is being fired and its just a problem with Visual Studio debugger that you are not hitting the break point. Try to write some file and see if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the codebehind namespace and/or class and see if that solves the problem. If so, it's probably due to another default.aspx page's events/controls interfering.

Comment: As mentioned in the examples the class is not "default" but original

Comment: Because of your practice of naming default.aspx classes to "original", I thought maybe that's conflicting somewhere. Did you try changing it to something else just for kicks? Maybe SITMComAU.TWS.originalXYZ. That will at least throw that theory out the window.

Comment: the page won't even run if the code behind class is not properly named or duplicated; it won't even compile. This can't be it.

Comment: I only changed the class name after the problem manifested itself. Renaming the page classes is not my regular practice ;-)